# PHP Multiple Filtering Links

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, filter

I am working on creating a filtering system for a mySQL database using dropdown menus. My system works when I search using one filter but I'm having a hard time getting them to stack. I am using GET to retrieve the filter they choose and I'm trying to save these and concatenate them to the next selection.

Right now my code gets all the variables possible:

```
$artistTag = $_GET['artistTag'];
$typeTag = $_GET['typeTag'];
$priceTag = $_GET['priceTag'];
$sizeTag = $_GET['sizeTag'];`
```

And here's where I'm having the issue:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM artData";
$conditions = array();

$filter = '';

if ($artistTag != "") {
    $conditions[] = "artistTag='$artistTag'";
    $artistFilter = "artistTag=".$artistTag."";
    $filter = $artistFilter;
}
if ($typeTag != "") {
    $conditions[] = "typeTag='$typeTag'";
    $typeFilter = "typeTag=".$typeTag."";
    $filter .= "&".$typeFilter."";
}
if ($priceTag != "") {
    $conditions[] = "priceTag='$priceTag'";
    $priceFilter = "priceTag=".$priceTag."";
    $filter .= "&".$priceFilter."";
}
if ($sizeTag != "") {
    $conditions[] = "sizeTag='$sizeTag'";
    $sizeFilter = "sizeTag=".$sizeTag."";
    $filter .= "&".$sizeFilter."";
}

$sql = $query;
if (count($conditions) > 0) {
    $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

I'm trying to append the links for additional filters with the previous filters using $filter.

```
<a href="index.php?artistTag='.$row[artistTag].''.$filter.'">'.$row[artist].'</a>
```

That way the next URL generated would be

> index.php?artistTag=picasso&sizeTag=large

This works occasionally but if I select the same filter again it doesn't replace the old one. I am open to suggestions on how to do this but it's important that the filters are applied through the drop-down menu links and not a form. I've tried searching the forums and I can't find a solution thus far. Thank you for taking the time to help!

**Edit:**
Kostas Mitsarakis was kind enough to help me get the code to get the tags previously searched and concatenate them into a prefix for the additional search tags. The problem is when new search tags are added it doesn't overwrite the tag of the same category. It also seems to not add the question mark and ampersand appropriately. This is my current code (simplified):

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'host');
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

$vars = array('artistTag', 'typeTag', 'priceTag', 'sizeTag');
$query = "SELECT * FROM artData ";
$filter = array();
$binds = array();
$i = 0;

$href = '<a href="index.php';

foreach($vars as $key => $value) { //For every attribute you want to take from $_GET
    if ($_GET[$value] != '') { //If the value is not empty
        $filter[] = $value." = :".$value; //Add it for WHERE clause
        $binds[':'.$value] = $_GET[$value]; //And also prepare the value
        if ($i == 0) { //This is for link creation
            $href .= '?'.$value.'='.$_GET[$value];
        } else {
            $href .= '&'.$value.'='.$_GET[$value];
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    if (!empty($filter)) { //If one or more $_GET variables are not empty
        $query .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $filter); //Concatenate at Where clause
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); //Prepare the statement
    $stmt->execute($binds); //And bind the values
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        print ''.$row[artist].' - '.$row[id].' - '.$row[priceTag].'</br>';
    }

    $stmt = null; //Close the connection
    $conn = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>debug mode</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        print ''.$href.'artistTag=ricker">Bruce Ricker</a></br>
        '.$href.'artistTag=picasso">Pablo Picasso</a></br>
        '.$href.'artistTag=dali">Salvador Dal&iacute</a></br></br>

        '.$href.'typeTag=drawing">Drawing</a></br>
        '.$href.'typeTag=painting">Painting</a></br></br>

        '.$href.'sizeTag=large">Large</a></br>
        '.$href.'sizeTag=medium">Medium</a></br>
        '.$href.'sizeTag=small">Small</a></br></br>';


        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not just use the `$_GET` global?

Comment: Where? I was trying to make it easier to concatenate the previous results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PDO with prepared statements for your `SELECT` query and a helper array for your link creation.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'your_database');
define('DB_USER', 'your_username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_password');

$vars = array('artistTag', 'typeTag', 'priceTag', 'sizeTag');
$query = "SELECT * FROM artData ";
$filter = array();
$binds = array();
$i = 0;

$href = '<a href="index.php';

foreach($vars as $key => $value) { //For every attribute you want to take from $_GET
    if ($_GET[$value] != '') { //If the value is not empty
        $filter[] = $value." = :".$value; //Add it for WHERE clause
        $binds[':'.$value] = $_GET[$value]; //And also prepare the value
        if ($i == 0) { //This is for link creation
            $href .= '?'.$value.'='.$_GET[$value];
        } else {
            $href .= '&'.$value.'='.$_GET[$value];
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    if (!empty($filter)) { //If one or more $_GET variables are not empty
        $query .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $filter); //Concatenate at Where clause
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); //Prepare the statement
    $stmt->execute($binds); //And bind the values
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo $row['id'].'<br />';
    }

    $stmt = null; //Close the connection
    $conn = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

**EDIT:**

To check if get variable is in use you can use something like the following (it needs to be modified).

```
$values = array(
    'artistTag'=>array(
        array(
            'url'=>'ricker',
            'text'=>'Bruce Ricker',
        ),
        array(
            'url'=>'picasso',
            'text'=>'Pablo Picasso',
        ),
        array(
            'url'=>'dali',
            'text'=>'Salvador Dal&iacute',
        ),
    ),
    'typeTag'=>array(
        array(
            'url'=>'drawing',
            'text'=>'Drawing',
        ),
        array(
            'url'=>'painting',
            'text'=>'Painting',
        ),
    ),
    'sizeTag'=>array(
        array(
            'url'=>'large',
            'text'=>'Large',
        ),
        array(
            'url'=>'medium',
            'text'=>'Medium',
        ),
        array(
            'url'=>'small',
            'text'=>'Small',
        ),
    ),
);

foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($_GET[$key])) {
        foreach($value as $s_key => $s_value) {
            echo $href.'?'.$key.'='.$s_value['url'].'>'.$s_value['text'].'</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This looks like exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm working on implementing it now and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, I think it's what you need. If I missed anything modify it to get the results you want.

Comment: Check the updated answer at:  foreach($result as $row)

Comment: Perfect! That worked for printing out the results. I'm just working on using the $href variable correctly now.

Comment: As soon as I get it working properly I'll mark the answer as solved!

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: I'm just having trouble finding where I use $href in my links to get the new dropdown menus to work.

Comment: Oh, this is a totally different section.

Comment: Well I can get the $href to work and add the tag. The problem is the new tag doesn't overwrite it, it just adds to it. I end up with urls ending like this: 'index.php?typeTag=painting?artist=ricker?artist=dali?artist=picasso'.

Comment: Edit the question with the code you currently use so I will be able to debug it.

Comment: I added my updated code to the question. The problem is if you search by artist again it doesn't overwrite the previous one. It seems the ? and & aren't being inserted appropriately either.

Comment: Ok, I 'll check it and I 'll tell you if you have to correct something.

Comment: Do you want to have multiple values for each tag in the URL?

Comment: No that's what I'm trying to avoid. Let's say they're searching by artist already and they click another artist. I need that new artist to overwrite the old one instead of adding another condition.

Comment: If you concatenate the href then you will have all the values of each variable.

Comment: Check my updated answer, experiment a bit and finally I 'm sure you will get what you need.

Comment: Okay thank you! I will mark your answer as solved and work through the rest of this on my own. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Would it be possible to do a foreach loop for each tag link leaving out that tag specifically? For example the artist href would contain the tags for type, price and size but not artist. The Type tag would contain the tags for artist, price and size but not type. I could then use these to let the user select a new tag in each corresponding category.

Comment: You can make 3 arrays and loop them separately.

Comment: Hey Kostas. Thanks to your code I got everything work great! I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. How would I test to see if 0 results are returned with this method? I can't seem to return a value from the $result variable.

Comment: if (count($result) < 1) { echo 'No results found'; }